# Whats the difference between the Job and JobDetail exactly in Quartz?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, jobs, job-scheduling, quartz

Why Quartz came up with separate class like `JobDetail`? when they can
accommodate all properties in `Job` class only

Is it a implementation flaw from the authors?

Comment: Which exact version are you talking about and what does the documentation say about these classes? And which programming language are you using?

Comment: I am asking about Java,http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/

Comment: And which version?

Comment: All the latest versions have these classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all both are interfaces.

an implementation of `Job` ie. its only method `void execute(JobExecutionContext)` is what gets called by the quartz scheduler in order to perform a desired task

> The interface to be implemented by classes which represent a 'job' to be performed.

---

`JobDetails` are meta data related to a `Job` implementation, they hold a reference to the `Job` you want to run and allow you to provide some additional data to your `Job`

> Conveys the detail properties of a given Job instance. JobDetails are to be created/defined with JobBuilder.
>
> Quartz does not store an actual instance of a Job class, but instead allows you to define an instance of one, through the use of a JobDetail.
>
> Jobs have a name and group associated with them, which should uniquely identify them within a single Scheduler.

---

this design decision here taken seems reasonable as it follows the **separation of concerns** approach.

the `Job` to be performed gets all its input data through its `JobExecutionContext` and does not need to care about any other quartz related properties like name or group of the job.

however, the quartz scheduler needs some additional information in order to run your `Job`. therefore, a `JobDetail` implementation is required holding this information.